# Как сделать последовательное выполнение транзакций в MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, asp.net-mvc

По сути я хочу добиться последовательного выполнения транзакций которые обычно выполняются параленльно.
В коде C# я создаю транзакцию с помощью SqlConnection.BeginTransaction() и выполняю чтении из таблицы, а после делаю апдейт данных в этой же таблице. Закрываю транзакицю transaction.Commit(). В случае если метод где я делаю все эти манипуляции запускаеться в нескольких потоках мне нужно что бы транзакции выполнялись последовательно ожидая завершения друг друга, при этом нужно что бы таблица была доступна для чтения.

Использовать уровень изоляции seriazable не получилось так как возможна ошибка сериализации.
Метод в котором я это делаю это контроллер asp.net core.

К слову, подобного эфекта мне удолась добится в postgresql там я использовал Exlusicve lock. Можно ли в MS SQL Server явно блокировать таблицы. Или другие идеи как решить эту задачу.

Comment: Можем вместо шаманства с транзакциями, выстроить свои задачи в очередь? Что то типа producer-consumer, например? Ну или прикрутить систему сообщений типа RabbitMQ?

Comment: Если вы хотите строго порядка бизнес-операций, то почему вы их выносите в разные потоки? Это тогда должна быть единая транзакция. Если вас не устраивают альтернатива выше типа рэббит/кафка, тогда вместо двух классов с транзакциями напишите их же без транзакций, а потом напишите третий, который откроет транзакцию, затем выполнит код из предыдущих двух классов в нужном порядке и закроет транзакцию. Поэтому для начала рекомендовал бы вынести бизнес-логику из контроллеров.